# LogStash - Read field content from file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Im using cidr filter to check if an IP si public or private.
The list of cidrs to check is now hardcoded in the filter but I need to read it from a file or using a meta-variable loaded at runtime.

```
cidr {
                id => "netflow-postproc-cidr-dst_addr"
                address => [ "%{[@metadata][netflow][dst_addr]}" ]
                network => [ "0.0.0.0/32", "10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16", "fc00::/7", "127.0.0.0/8", "::1/128","169.254.0.0/16", "fe80::/10","224.0.0.0/4", "ff00::/8","255.255.255.255/32" ]
                add_field => { "[@metadata][netflow][dst_locality]" => "private" }
            }
```

Something like this:

```
cidr.yml => [@metadata][private_cidr]
```

and then

```
...
network => [@metadata][private_cidr]
...
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`network_path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-cidr.html#plugins-filters-cidr-network_path) setting instead of `network`:

```
        cidr {
            id => "netflow-postproc-cidr-dst_addr"
            address => [ "%{[@metadata][netflow][dst_addr]}" ]
            network_path => "/path/to/cidr.yml"
            add_field => { "[@metadata][netflow][dst_locality]" => "private" }
        }
```

Comment: Not specific for cidr filter, is it possibile to load a yml file into a variable?

Comment: Well, it always depends on what you want to do with the content... There's also the [`translate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html) filter that allows you to do some matching